# Send a message to spring-messaging listener?

Tags: spring, spring-messaging

How can I send a message to one Spring-messaging @MessageMapping anotated method?
I have the next code:

```
@MessageMapping("/miprocesadorpagos")
public void miProcesadorPagos(
        @Payload final Message<CobroBancario> message
        )
{

    System.out.println("GreetingController::miProcesadorPagos():  Ejecucion!");

}
```

and I'm trying to send a message with:

```
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/app/miprocesadorpagos", message.getPayload());
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/app/queue/miprocesadorpagos", message.getPayload());
    messagingTemplate.send("/app/queue/miprocesadorpagos", message);
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("app/miprocesadorpagos", message.getPayload());
    messagingTemplate.send("app/miprocesadorpagos", message);
    messagingTemplate.send("/app/queue/miprocesadorpagos", message);
    messagingTemplate.send("/app/topic/miprocesadorpagos", message);
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/app/topic/miprocesadorpagos", message.getPayload());

    messagingTemplate.send("miprocesadorpagos", message);
    messagingTemplate.send("/miprocesadorpagos", message);
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("miprocesadorpagos", message.getPayload());
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/miprocesadorpagos", message.getPayload());
    messagingTemplate.send("/topic/miprocesadorpagos", message);
    messagingTemplate.send("topic/miprocesadorpagos", message);
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/miprocesadorpagos", message.getPayload());
```

where messagingTemplate of type org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate that create Spring by default.

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
```

But don't work.
message is of type org.springframework.messaging.Message

Comment: Do you want to send a message to the topic `/app/miprocesadorpagos` or do you want to invoke that method?

Comment: I want send a message to this queue (or topic?).  I'm receiving a message from a org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener (with @JmsListener) and I want send the message to the other listener annotated with   @MessageMapping("/miprocesadorpagos").